# Печать на принтер, как отловить замятие или отсутствие бумаги?

Tags: c#

Добрый день.
Встала задача сделать программу для автоматической печати на принтер.
Но есть условие - как отловить замятие или отсутствие бумаги? Это вообще возможно в универсальном порядке (т.е. не под каждый принтер отдельно)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте [IsOutOfPaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.isoutofpaper.aspx)

> Gets a value that indicates whether the printer needs to be reloaded with paper of the size required for the current job.

Answer (score 0):

Под каждый принтер вряд ли. Есть принтеры, дешевые как правило (иногда в терминалах оплаты используются), которые особо информации не дают. В свое время максимум, что делал - мониторил очередь печати Windows. Как превышала лимит по зависшим докам, значит явно что-то не то, а что конкретно только на месте выяснить можно было. А так да, выше ссылка годная штука